Connect Mobile app Flutter to Keycloak to FIDO2 Authentication
I'm trying to connect my mobile app in Flutter with Keycloak and i'm having trouble to implement the code to connecto first to Keycloak and register a user and a passkey.
I don't want to redirect my app to the Keycloak URL, i want to do it without redirecting to the Keycloak url.
I've tried all dart packages conserning Keycloak and appauth but nothing works
I've tried all packages in dart to connect to Keycloak and no one gives the passkey generate functionality
